# GameplayKit GKPolygonObstacle Not Working With GKGoal

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics, gameplay-kit

Similarly to a question I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571104/obstacles-with-gameplaykit), I am now realizing that the problem is more trivial that I anticipated, as this works for some elements of `GameplayKit` but not others..

I have an obstacle, an `SKNode`, that I am trying to define as a `GKPolygonObstacle` that can be used by an agent, a `GKAgent2D`, as an obstacle to avoid when moving in an `SKScene` I have set up.

I have looked into to [Apple's AgentsCatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AgentsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) to see how they use `GKObstacle` with an agent in the `GameplayKit` method:

```
goalToAvoidObstacles:(nonnull NSArray<GKObstacle *> *) maxPredictionTime:(NSTimeInterval)
```

When I use the following code in my own project to create `GKCircleObstacle` objects, I find that the agent quite nicely navigates around and *avoids* these circular obstacles quite nicely depending on the weight I give it (importance level).

Here is the code that I am using:

```
NSArray<GKObstacle *> *obstacles2 = @[
    [self addObstacleAtPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                             CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 150)],
    [self addObstacleAtPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 200,
                             CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 150)],
    [self addObstacleAtPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 200,
                             CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 150)], ];
  
enemy.avoidGoal = [GKGoal goalToAvoidObstacles:obstacles2 maxPredictionTime:1];
[enemy.agent.behavior setWeight:100 forGoal:enemy.avoidGoal];
```

With the following method that creates and adds these obstacles: (this is directly pulled from Apple's source code for the AgentsCatalog)

```
- (GKObstacle *)addObstacleAtPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    SKShapeNode *circleShape = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:50];
    circleShape.lineWidth = 2.5;
    circleShape.fillColor = [SKColor grayColor];
    circleShape.strokeColor = [SKColor redColor];
    circleShape.zPosition = 1;
    circleShape.position = point;
    [self addChild:circleShape];

    GKCircleObstacle *obstacle = [GKCircleObstacle obstacleWithRadius:50];
    obstacle.position = (vector_float2){point.x, point.y};

    return obstacle;
}
```

This works great as the enemy avoids these circles as it tries to move to a certain changing position in the scene.

## ISSUE

When I attempt to recreate this `GKGoal` behavior by using `GKPolygonObstacle` objects in place of the `GKCircleObstacle` objects, the enemy agent cannot seem to identify the polygon obstacles as obstacles to avoid for the behavioral goal. Here is how I am attempting to add these obstacles:

```
NSArray<GKObstacle *> *obstacles = [SKNode obstaclesFromNodePhysicsBodies:innerMapArray];

// Take this array of GKPolygonObstacle objects and add it 
// to the GKGoal of the enemy as obstacles to avoid

enemy.avoidGoal = [GKGoal goalToAvoidObstacles:obstacles maxPredictionTime:1];
[enemy.agent.behavior setWeight:100 forGoal:enemy.avoidGoal];
```

What is most frustrating about this, is that I know that the array is correctly creating an `NSArray` of `GKPolygonObstacle` objects as I have used this approach for pathfinding as well (before I decided to painfully implement `GameplayKit` and it's seek, avoid, and wander goals). Here is how I was using this **innerMapArray**:

```
- (NSArray *)findPathWithNode:(SKNode *)nodeToFindPath {
    
    NSArray *obstacles = [SKNode obstaclesFromNodePhysicsBodies:innerMapArray];
    GKObstacleGraph *graph = [GKObstacleGraph graphWithObstacles:obstacles bufferRadius:35.0f];


    // Set up enemy and target
    GKGraphNode2D *target = [GKGraphNode2D nodeWithPoint:vector2((float)character.position.x, (float)character.position.y)];
    GKGraphNode2D *enemy = [GKGraphNode2D nodeWithPoint:vector2((float)nodeToFindPath.position.x, (float)nodeToFindPath.position.y)];
    
    [graph connectNodeUsingObstacles:enemy];
    [graph connectNodeUsingObstacles:target];
    
    /// Create tracking path
    NSArray *pathPointsFound = [graph findPathFromNode:enemy toNode:target];

    
    return pathPointsFound;
}
```

This method quite nicely returns the points at which the most efficient path should include to go around obstacles I am telling the enemy to avoid when trying to reach a location.

- So the real question becomes: why does the `GKGoal` accept `GKCircleObstacle` objects but not `GKPolygonObstacle` objects?

If someone can help me figure out how to convert these `SKNode` objects into acceptable obstacles that register with the `GKGoal` I would be extremely appreciative. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very strange / simple answer, and I'm afraid I now have the obstacles being avoided (more than not at least..) by the enemy.

- Giving the `GKGoal` for avoiding obstacles a very *low* `maxPredictionTime` (t < 10) seems to make the agent ignore the obstacles completely. Any prediction time of 10 or greater + a weight of 100+ seems to cause correct behavior.

Comment: Interesting -> I have the opposite behavior t <10 worked fine but t>=10 just ignored everything

Comment: I wish Apple had generated a slightly more thorough platform. It has great potential, just not executed properly the first go around. hoping for an update soon..

Comment: Thats so true! I just gave up on this and rolling my own agents.

Comment: Yea, it pretty much works, ... except for boundaries :( It gets confused :)